# Redirect local mail addressed to root, but don’t accept mail at root@my.org

Tags: postfix

On my Postfix mail server, I would like to redirect local mail sent to root to my virtual mailbox me@my.org. At the same time, I do not want to receive any outside mail at root@my.org. Is such a configuration at all possible?

My motivation is to receive notifications generated by services like Cron conveniently in my inbox at me@my.org. Such notifications usually get sent to user `root`. I have been able to set up the redirection as desired:

1. Daemon sends mail to `root`.
2. Postfix appends `$myorigin` (`append_at_myorigin = yes`, must not be changed).
3. `root@my.org` is looked up and mapped through `virtual_alias_maps`.
4. Mail is delivered to mailbox `me@my.org`.

However, with this setup anyone can send mail to root@my.org. I’d rather not have this address as a public alias of me@my.org. The behaviour I would like to have:

- locally: mail sent to `root` → delivered to me@my.org
- remote clients: attempt to send mail to root@my.org → 550 5.1.1 User Unknown

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myhostname = mail.my.org
mydomain = my.org
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = my.org
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

/etc/mailname:

```
my.org
```

/etc/postfix/vmailbox:

```
me@my.org         me@my.org
postmaster@my.org postmaster@my.org
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
me@my.org         me@my.org
me2@my.org        me@my.org
root@my.org       me@my.org
postmaster@my.org postmaster@my.org
```

/etc/aliases:

```
postmaster: postmaster@my.org
root: root@my.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented by adding additional recipient restrictions that reject mail to the address root@my.org. Recipient restrictions are checked after the relay restrictions.

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# Relay restrictions are unchanged.
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  reject_unauth_destination

# New: disallow sending mail to root from outside this host.
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

The `check_recipient_access` database contains just an entry for the root address. Don’t forget to run `postmap` on the file.

/etc/postfix/access:

```
root@my.org REJECT
```

`permit_mynetworks` is evaluated before `check_recipient_access`, so mail sent locally by Cron etc. still gets through. For recipients not in the database the access check doesn’t apply, they fall through to the default ‘permit’ result.